# Thank them FOR or FROM us?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

Could you elaborate on the differences and proper use of these two phrases, please:

- Thank them **for** us
- Thank them **from** us

Thank you!

Comment: Use the first to mean "Thank them on our behalf."   Don't use the second.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your confusion with this - some English speakers *do* say the latter of the two, even though it is technically incorrect.

"Thank them *for* us" is an idiomatic way of asking someone to say 'thank-you' to someone else *on your behalf*.

"Thank them *from* us" is not technically correct, I believe people actually mean to say "**say thank-you to *[x]* from us**", the meaning of which is the same as above. But if you just said "say thank you [x]" without specifying that it is from you, it sounds like you are asking the person to say 'thank-you' on their own behalf, not yours. This is quite common - parents may remind their children to be polite by saying "say thank you to [x]", so it seems necessary to add "from us".

Comment: So might "Thank my parents for me" be ambiguous?

Comment: Another context where it's actually significantly *more* acceptable to use **from** rather than ***for*** to reference the speaker as the "vicarious agent" is *Give Mummy a kiss **for** me*. But I wouldn't want to get bogged down in some hypothetical distinction between *pretend the kiss came **from** me* and *kiss him **for** my benefit.*

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, not at all. You're saying who to thank, and as they are doing it *for* you, that is on your behalf.

Comment: I've heard "Thanks from us!"  or "Say thanks from us!"  but I don't think I've ever heard "Thank them from us", even once.  Is there a specific region or dialect where you've heard that?

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't call either of these examples "proper".

If you want to ask someone to say "thanks" to someone else, on your behalf,  I wouldn't personally use either of these. Although I know what you mean, they're a little awkward TBH. Also, issuing a direct command in the imperative without saying please first, can be viewed as quite rude or aggressive, possibly even slighly dismissive or insincere. Obviously this would depend on the context, but you didn't provide any context.

There are much better ways to express this kind of thing. Instead, I would use something like "Please pass on our thanks to them". or "Please tell them we are very thankful".   "Please thank them on our behalf".  "Please let them know how grateful we are", etc.

Comment: "Thank them for us!"  is perfectly OK.